# Calculate this power?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, tetration

Let $a$ is a positive real number. If ${a^{{a^{{a^{16}}}}}} = 16$ how much is ${a^{{a^{{a^{12}}}}}}$?

Comment: If you shared your work with us, it would expedite a cogent reply.

Comment: I dont have one.OK?

Comment: Although inelegant, brute-force numerical methods gives $a=\sqrt[4]{2}$.  Although this isn't a solution, it can be used to check your answer.

Comment: Hi iam looking for an algebraic solution ...if there is one that is...

Comment: In an effort to get started, why not take logarithms?

Comment: If answer is $x$,   $  x^{1/12} = 16^{1/16} $

Comment: I dont think that taking logarithms leads somewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the function $f(x)=a^x$

The equation $$a\uparrow a\uparrow a\uparrow 16=16$$

can be written in the form $$f(f(f(16)))=16$$

Obviously, the solution of the equation $f(16)=16$ solves this equation.
Because of the monotony of $f(f(f(16)))-16$, it is the only solution, so 
we have $$a^{16}=16$$

Therefore, we have $$a^4=2$$ or $$a^{12}=8$$

Furthermore, we have $$a^{a^{12}}=a^8=4$$

and finally $$a^{a^{a^{12}}}=a^4=2$$

Comment: Peter i think you are right.Thanks

Comment: The numerical analysis with PARI/GP gives the same result.

Comment: OK i will try this package as well.

Comment: More general, there are also (complex) solutions where $g(g(g(g(16)))) = 16$ but $g(16) \ne 16$. Se for instance the complex solutions for $h(h(16))=16$ using W/A "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solxe+x^x=16"